# Unable to run a subroutine after onWait

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have two subroutines:CommandButton2_Click,CommandButton1_Click in which cmd2_click will call cmd1_click by using the below statement:

```
Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "CommandButton1_Click"
```

But I'm getting the below error while executing the above statement.

here is a screen shot of error
[image]

Comment: It looks like you need to specify where the macro is located. Or make it `public` if it currently is private.

Comment: @enderland It is public only.. Both the subroutines are public

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly prefix the programatic sheetname followed by a dot as in below example.

Try below code :

```
  Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "Sheet1.CommandButton1_Click"
```

If you search for CommandButton1_Click procedure in object browser you will see its a private function on the sheet in which you have kept the command button.

[image]

Also make sure your macro is enabled. Kindly refer below link.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Jqp_WQRT6M

Comment: It resides on a sheet named Launch @user2063626 and macro's are also enabled. Without enabling the macros i will not be able to click the button. Right?